# Missing Dll in dependency walker

Tags: c++, dll, dependency-walker

I am having a dll and which I am opening into the dependency walker with platform visual studio 2003 and OS is 2000. and my that dll find all dependency.

But when I am going to open that dll in to tha another system which is having OS- windows7 and visual studio 2010, I found missing dlls errors.

```
GDIPLUS.DLL,
GPSVC.DLL,
IESHIMS.DLL.
```

above listed 3 dll were missing. when I have downloded those dlls and put them into the same location where my dll is residing, I am finding below listed missing dlls list.

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-2-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L2-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-OBSOLETE-L1-2-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-2.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-2-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-2.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-2-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TIMEZONE-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-ADVAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-OLE32-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-2-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L2-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-1.DLL,
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-WINSVC-L1-2-0.DLL,
SYSNTFY.DLL.
```

It is may be because of configuration issue, please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These reported errors for `GDIPLUS.DLL`, `GPSVC.DLL` and `IESHIMS.DLL` are false positives. The static analysis that Dependency Walker does will sometimes report errors like this. But when you attempt to load the DLL you will find, I believe, that it loads successfully.

You do not need to download these three DLLs. You should absolutely reverse that action. Remove those files from the directory where your DLL resides.

Comment: This test was basically to interop my dll into visual studio 2010. I could interop the same dll into visual studio 2003. Please guide me how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: I don't understand that question. Could you perhaps explain a little more.

Comment: Actually I have some xx.dll and whose function I want use in C# application with Visual Studio 2010. I can interop this dll function into Visual Studio 2003 by creating a console application. SO my Problem is I want to interop that dll method into Visual Studio 2010 with C# web apllication, but I am not able to add reference of that dll into my web application. Please help me out. thanks in advance.

Comment: That's quite a different question from the one asked. If the DLL is unmanaged, then you cannot add a reference. That's only for managed assemblies.

Answer (score 13):

All the API-MS-WIN-XXX 'missing' dll's are really [API-sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802935(v=vs.85).aspx) (sometimes referred to as 'virtual DLLs'). OP's "Dependency walker" version just wasn't updated since before their invention
(but version 2.2 should not have issues).
[Here are some details](http://ofekshilon.com/2016/03/27/on-api-ms-win-xxxxx-dll-and-other-dependency-walker-glitches/).

> **See also** https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/releases
> (for an open-source alternative).