# C++ API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL dependency issue

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies

I have a C++ project in x64 release mode (developed with VS2015) that I'm trying to run it from another machine. However, the program failed to run, and according to dependency walker, it seems missing `API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL`.

According to another post [Missing Dll in dependency walker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778284/missing-dll-in-dependency-walker), it seems to be false alarm. However, I still couldn't ignore it and get my .exe working on another computer.

Do I need to make changes to my project configurations? If so, what kind of change could fix this?

Comment: Did you deploy the appropriate Visual Studio redistributable package to the target machine?

Comment: The linked post that talks about false alarms refers to different DLLs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The target machine is clean, which means no Visual Studio is installed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, it is different DLLs, but essentially they are talking about the same issue. I've searched the specific DLL I mentioned in the question and they are there in the C drive of the target machine whilst the executable is stopped because it can't find the DLL.

Comment: No, they are not talking about the same issue. There is a reason that answer specifically lists three DLLs as being ignorable. It says nothing about this DLL (which is not actually a real DLL, per the _other_ answer on that page).

Comment: Make sure that the executable you are trying to run on the other PC was built in Release mode and that all the 3rd party library dependencies were also built in Release mode and with VS2015 or newer. According to the Visual Studio licence you are not permitted to run a debug mode application on a machine that does not have Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 0):

The target machine needs [the Visual Studio 2015 redistributable package](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=2082) for runtime support.

Comment: I installed it as recommended, but the problem persists.