# How to find which DLL failed in "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing" in python?

Tags: python, debugging, dll, anaconda

## Context

Are there commands to enhance the error message that is received such that python displays which `.dll` file it cannot find?

For error:

```
python test_cv2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_cv2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

(py38) E:\somepath>
```

I would like to determine which `.dll` file is actually not being found. To do so, I downloaded and run `DependenciesGui.exe` from [this repository.](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies). Next I fed the `DependenciesGui.exe` the `cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd` which indicates `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll` is missing, amongst others.

I currently do not have a way to verify that the `.dll` files that are reported missing by `dependenciesGUI.exe` are also the files that python 3.8 is not finding in the anaconda environment.

A way to implicitly verify that the python 3.8 missing `.dll` files are the same as the same files reported missing by `dependenciesGUI.exe` would be to download and paste all the missing `.dll` files into `../system32/`. Followed by inspecting if the error message dissapears/changes. However one of the `.dll` files reported missing is: `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll` which I am not yet able to find (online). Also I tried to cheat to copy and rename `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-0.dll` to `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll` but that (luckily) doesn't enable the `dpendenciesGUI.exe` to recognize the `.dll` file as found.

## Question

How can I make the error message/traceback of python explicitly mention which `.dll` file is (the first `.dll` file that is) not found?

## Note

This is not about solving the `xy-problem` of installing `opencv`.

Comment: For information, I am not sure api-ms-win-* are really missing, it could just be a false positive from `Dependencies`: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778284/missing-dll-in-dependency-walker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Although it is probably not completely impossible, it would require to bind a tool like `dependenciesGUI` in Python, in order to be able to call it in that given context (namely taking into account the actually search path for dll in Python and already loaded dynamics libraries). It would be quite a lot of work for little gain. Indeed, the default search path in Python>=3.8 on Windows should be very similar to the one of `dependenciesGUI`, so that the missing dll should be the same. Personally, I'm developing pre-compiled binary distributions for Python, and so far `dependenciesGUI` was enough to identify the missing libraries at Python import.